# Why is this next.js project rendering the component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to understand how React.memo works and created the following next.js project. I was expecting the `Test` component to render only once as I'm passing it the same prop, but it renders every time.

I added the `` const txt = `${msg}${Math.random()}`; `` line for testing purpose, but I get the same behavior if I remove it - the component renders three times at every page. With it, I get the something similar to the lines below:

```
Test: test0.22056845903240596
Test: test0.15269599756070829
Test: test0.8253090140192767
```

I was expecting:

```
Test: test0.22056845903240596
Test: test0.22056845903240596
Test: test0.22056845903240596
```

Also it looks like the `areEqual` function defined at `/components/test.tsx` never gets called.

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-monad-uqsevi?file=/pages/index.tsx:0-417)

### /components/test.tsx

```
import React from "react";

type TestProps = {
  msg: string;
};

function areEqual(prevProps: any, nextProps: any) {
  console.log(prevProps, nextProps);
  return prevProps === nextProps;
}

export default React.memo<TestProps>(({ msg }) => {
  console.log("Test rendered");
  const txt = `${msg}${Math.random()}`;
  return <div>Test: {txt}</div>;
}, areEqual);
```

### /pages/index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const DynamicTest = dynamic(() => import("../components/test"), { ssr: false });

export default () => (
  <div>
    <DynamicTest msg="test"></DynamicTest>
    <DynamicTest msg="test"></DynamicTest>
    <DynamicTest msg="test"></DynamicTest>
    <Link href="/second">
      <a>Go to second page</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

### /pages/second.tsx

```
import Link from "next/link";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const DynamicTest = dynamic(() => import("../components/test"), { ssr: false });

export default () => (
  <div>
    <DynamicTest msg="test"></DynamicTest>
    <DynamicTest msg="test"></DynamicTest>
    <DynamicTest msg="test"></DynamicTest>
    <Link href="/">
      <a>Go to first page</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I'm guessing the rendered node is memoized for each instance of the component, not globally. That means the memoized result will be used when each instance gets updated.

Comment: Should I use useMemo instead of React.memo?

Comment: that's a better alternative, you'd return the DynamicTest element from the callback and render it multiple times